# How to display the most liked post when the likes are stored in another table php

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a small CMS, where posts have likes. I store the likes in another table so that the liked posts can be found in the users 'dashboard'.

"Likes" table

```
» likes
    - id
    - user
    - post
    - timestamp
```

But now I would like to show the most liked posts in a page. How to achieve that?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: [count](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count).

Comment: and [**group by**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Show some code of what you have tried. Also what is the specific issue you are facing? It seems like you have to a table join.

Comment: are you using any framework or core php ? can you update some code how you are doing ?

Comment: I'm currently using core php, but if there is any light frameworks for this, I'd be glad to use it. And tbh I haven't started yet. I have checked out tons of vidoes and articles around the internet, but haven't found how to do it.. that's why I came here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make a function that will get the details of the post

```
public function get_post_details(){
    $sql = 'SELECT pt.id, pt.details <- (you can select whatever you want to display) ';
    $sql .= 'FROM post_table pt ';

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    $result = $query->row();
    foreach ($result as $key => $value)
    {
        $result->post_likes = $this->get_post_likes_by_id($result->id);
    }

    return ( $query->num_rows() ) ? $result : FALSE;
}
```

Then make the second function that will get all the likes in like_table assuming that every post like of the user will add one row in the table like this

If first_user likes post1 the table of likes will store data like this

```
likes_table 

id    post_id    user_likes
1     1          1
```

then the second user user likes the post1 it should be like this

```
likes_table 

id   post_id   user_likes
1    1         1
2    1         2
```

user_likes is the id of the user who likes the post

second function

```
public function get_post_likes_by_id($post_id) {
    $params = [];

    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(lt.id) total_likes ';
    $sql .= 'FROM likes_table lt ';
    $sql .= 'WHERE lt.post_id = ? ';

    $params[] = $post_id;

    $query = $this->db->query($sql, $params);

    $likes = $query->result();
    $data = [];

    foreach ($likes as $like)
    {
        array_push($data, $like->total_likes);
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: *"W3schools are the best tutorial site"* - Huh?! By whose standards?

Comment: @fred Just me LOL :D

Comment: it's a personal preference. If you feel it is, then you should specify that in your answer ;-) (wink). some may not share your beliefs.

Comment: I will keep that in mind :D

Comment: yeah, some guys don't like W3 Schools at all. Just trying to save you from some possible extremists ;-)

Comment: @fred Thank you by the way :D

Comment: hi there... i'm a beginner in php, but I didn't quite understand you meant by (lt.id) or by pt.id -> is it lt = likes_table and pt = post_table

thank you

Comment: and also... i have tried replacing the lt with likes_table and pt with post_table but all i get is an array of all the results and not individual posts with like counts.

Comment: @SoulS. the lt or pt is an alias. SQL aliases are used to give a database table, or a column in a table, a temporary name. so when you try to rename the lt to likes_table then you should also rename the other columns like likes_table.id, likes_table.name.

Comment: It is required to give an aliases in table when you joining other table. for example. when you join likes_table and post_table and the two tables has a column of ID and you want to select the both ID. you cannot query it the output is this SELECT id, id. the correct way is this SELECT lt.id, pt.id. lt.id refers the id to the likes_table and the pt.id refers to the post_table

Comment: @SoulS. If this answer solved your problem please mark it checked.

Comment: @MichaelAmaleona it did not work actually.. i have tried both the things you have suggested. Oh... and btw, I also have "unique ids" for posts, (ex. `uid` => 'd4d619b324') so.. the likes then in the likes table a column like this is stored aswell (`post` => 'd4d619b324') to specify a like... but I have modified your code... still didn't work

I get something like this as a result > http://prntscr.com/by64rj

Comment: I update my answer please check it

Comment: it's says that you are calling to undefined method, I believe it's because of $query->row() ... i'm actually writing it in vanilla php, not Codeignitor

Comment: you can refer to the documentation in vanilla php to get the sql result. Im just giving you the concept. and I think I already answer your question about How to display the most liked post when the likes are stored in another table php. the proper way doing that is another question since your question is not direct to the point. if you want to know how to execute sql in vanilla php you should ask another question

Comment: @MichaelAmaleona HI! thank you very, very much. I know understood what you were going for. After some thoughtful time, I realized what you were aiming for. I guess I couldn't before, because I was a stressed.. I marked your answer right :) and again, thank you and

have a nice day